# Problems with a foreach loop in a SimpleXMLelement

Tags: php

I'm trying to teach myself to handle the SimpleXMP_read_file command / object.

So I have looked deeply into the problem at "simpleXMLElement attributes and foreach" (
[simpleXMLElement attributes and foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533308/simplexmlelement-attributes-and-foreach) ).

copied it bit by bit into my PHP browser and ran it.

```
test.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response result="0">
    <reports>
        <get count="2">
            <row a="first" b="second" comment="test" c=""/>
            <row a="first1" b="second2" comment="test2" c=""/>
        </get>
    </reports>
</response>
```

modified the php like this:
PHP:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
$rows = $xml->xpath('reports/get/row');
foreach($rows as $row)
{

        foreach($row->attributes() as $key) 
        {               
           echo ('test: '.$key['a'] .' '.$key['b'].' '.$key['comment'].' '.$key['c'].'<br>') ;
        }
}
```

I get no errors but only 2 lines :

```
test
test
```

No data.

Can anyone tell me why ?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a `foreach` over `$row->attributes()`.  Therefore *each* iteration of the loop is a *different* attribute.  None of the attributes have a `$key['a']` value set.

You probably want to do:

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    $key = $row->attributes();
    echo 'test: '.$key['a'] .' '.$key['b'].' '.$key['comment'].' '.$key['c'].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after doing a `print_r($rows);` i have got the following. Now you can access the array elements and class objects directly by `$row->attributes['a']` etc.

```
 foreach($rows as $row){
     $xmlObjElement = json_decode(json_encode((array)$row), TRUE);
     foreach($xmlObjElement as $fo){
        print_r( $fo );
     }
 }
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [a] => first1
    [b] => second2
    [comment] => test2
    [c] =>
)
```

Now you can access like `$fo['a']` etc...

Comment: to convert the object to array.

Comment: There's gotta be a better/cleaner way to do that.

Comment: the code you provided `$key = $row->attributes();` did not give the result to get `$key['a']` ...yeah there could be a better way. But to access the SimxmlObject i found it easier.

Comment: I think you may have to do `(string)$key['a']` because SimpleXML gives you its own objects.  When you concat `$key['a']` to a string, it auto-converts it.